# Finding complementary function of non-constant coefficients ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine the complementary function for the homogeneous equation which satisfies the given initial conditions.

$(3+t)x''(t)+(2+t)x'(t)-x(t)=(3+t)^2  \space\space \space \forall \space  t > 0 $ subject to $x(0)=0$ and $x'(0)=1$

One independent solution to the homogeneous equation is $e^{-t}$

How would I find the CF of a non-constant coefficients ODE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the equation by the method of reduction of order since you already have a solution of the equation. 
$$x(t)=e^{-t}v(t)$$
I got for the homogeneous equation the following solution
$$x(t)=c_1e^{-t}+c_2(t+2)$$
With the method of reduction of order you should be able to solve the inhomogeneous equation..

After substitution I got a first order DE
$$(t+3)v''-(t+4)v'=e^t(t+3)^2$$
$$\frac {(t+3)v''-v'}{(t+3)^2}-\frac {v'}{t+3}=e^t$$
$$\left (\frac {v'}{(t+3)}\right )'-\frac {v'}{t+3}=e^t$$
$$\left (\frac {v'}{(t+3)}\right )'e^{-t}-\frac {v'}{t+3}e^{-t}=1$$
$$\left (\frac {v'}{(t+3)} e^{-t}\right)'=1$$
Integrate
$$\left (\frac {v'}{(t+3)} e^{-t}\right)=t+K$$
$$ v'=e^{t}(t+K)(t+3)$$
Integrate to get $v(t)$
$$ \implies v(t)=\int e^{t}(t+K)(t+3)dt$$

---

**Edit** after @Lutzl 's right comment

$$(3+t)x''(t)+(2+t)x'(t)-x(t)=(3+t)^2$$
$$(3+t)x''(t)+(2+t)x'(t)+\color{red}{x'-x'}-x(t)=(3+t)^2$$
$$(3+t)(x''+x'(t))-(x'+x(t))=(3+t)^2  $$
Substitute $v=x'+x$ the equation is  a first order one. 
$$(3+t)v'(t)-v(t)=(3+t)^2$$
It's of the form $(\frac f g)'=1$
$$\implies \left (\frac v {t+3}\right)'=1$$
After integration
$$v=(t+3)(t+K) \implies x'+x= (t+3)(t+K)$$
$$(xe^t)'=(t+3)(t+K)e^t$$
Integrate
$$xe^t=\int (t+3)(t+K)e^t dt$$
Finally
$$\boxed {x(t)=Ce^{-t}+K(t+2)+t^2-3}$$

Comment: The method of undetermined coefficients is not applicable for ODE with non-constant coefficients. Change the right side and the method breaks down.

Comment: Thanks @LutzL will correct it

Comment: @LutzL Can I ask you for more information since I am sure that a polynomial is a solution to this differential equation...why can't we use that to solve the diff equation.. I cant get anything on the web on the limit of the undetermined coefficientes method for DE with variables coefficients.. Do you have a link Thanks in advance for any information.

Comment: It just does not work for variable coefficients, and there is no reason why it should. If you change the right side from the specifically selected $r(t)=(t+3)^2$ to just $r(t)=(t+3)$ or $r(t)=(t+2)^2$ or..., then the equation $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{y'+y}{t+3}\right)=\frac{r(t)}{(t+3)^2}~\text{ or }~y'+y=(t+3)\int\frac{r(t)}{(t+3)^2}\,dt$$ will lead to non-polynomial anti-derivatives resp. non-polynomial-exponential right sides in the second formulation. One has then to use a more general tool like the variation of constants method.

Comment: @Lutzl Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

The order reduction approach tells you that if you are given a solution $y_1(t)$, then you search for the second solution in the form $y_2(t)=y_1(t)u(t)$. Here that gives
$$
(3+t)u''-(4+t)u'=0\implies u'=Ce^t(3+t),~~u=Ce^t(2+t)+D.
$$
This gives the second basis function as $y_2(t)=(2+t)$.

---

Or take the first basis solution as inspiration to set $v=y'+y$ to get the reduced equation
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{v(t)}{3+t}\right)=1\implies v=(3+t)(C+t),\\~~y=De^{-t}+e^{-t}\int(3+t)(C+t)e^t\,dt=C(2+t)+De^{-t}+e^{-t}\int(3+t)te^t\,dt
$$